# Firestore JS SDK - How to access FirestoreErrorCode enum?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to access Firestore error codes enum with the JS SDK?

I mean, something like `firebase.firestore.FirestoreErrorCode`

I need to access them in order to translate my app errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the errors defined here - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/src/util/error.ts

It looks like `FirestoreErrorCode` and `FirestoreError` are exported from the index of the package.

`FirestoreErrorCode` is an union type of the possible error codes while `FireStoreError` is a throwable Error object.

Because `FirestoerErrorCode` is defined as a union of literal strings you can't use those strings directly in your code.  If they were defined an enum you would be able to access values through the enum properties.

Comment: is it the only way to access all the firebase services error codes to write them separately in my code? I can't find any way to import them

Answer (score 1):

To avoid typing error, you can use `satisfies` (available from TypeScript 4.9)

```
if (error.code === "permission-denied" satisfies FirestoreErrorCode) {
    // OK
}
if (error.code === "permision-denied" satisfies FirestoreErrorCode) {
    // Typing error raised
}
```

For Firebase Authentication, you can access enum like this:

```
import { AuthErrorCodes } from 'firebase/auth';

if (error.code === AuthErrorCodes.USER_DELETED) {
    ...
}
```